# Azure: How to create single file rather than multiple from external table?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

So I have setup an external file to pull some data to a blob however when doing this it produces multiple files rather than the one I was expecting.

When I asked a colleague about this they advised its because of the distribution set on the table and that I can use top to force it to push into a single file.

Is there a better solution to this?

Unfortunately I am coming from the Teradata platform with not much knowledge on Azure.  I'm open to other methods of extracting this data to blob CSV I was just told by this colleague that using external tables would be the fastest method to extract.  I have to pull out about 340GB in total.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE [dataplatform_dataecosystem] WITH (TYPE = HADOOP, LOCATION = N'abfss://dataecosystem@(removed server name).dfs.core.windows.net', CREDENTIAL = [msi_cred])
GO
```

So we have the file format setup:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL FILE FORMAT [eff_td_csv] WITH (FORMAT_TYPE = DELIMITEDTEXT, FORMAT_OPTIONS (FIELD_TERMINATOR = N'|', USE_TYPE_DEFAULT = False), DATA_COMPRESSION = N'org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec')
GO
```

And we have external table setup:

```
create external table devl_trade.IRI_Test with
(
    Location = 'usr-data-engineering/rdp-extracts/cal'
    ,File_Format = [eff_td_csv]
    ,Data_Source = [dataplatform_dataecosystem]
)
AS
Select * from live_view.calendar
```

Comment: Can you share more details as to how you have tried already ? what is this external file and some snip would help suggest better. However, if you wish to just copy, try [Copy data tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/quickstart-create-data-factory-copy-data-tool#start-the-copy-data-tool)

Comment: @KarthikBhyresh-MT - I have added a few bits of code to show how we have it set at present.  This is just on a test table but this also produces the multiple files.

Comment: Sorry correct me if wrong, you want to store  this 340GB file into adls as a single csv file ?

Comment: Correct, zipped.  I may consider breaking the data up into some smaller chunks but they will still be several GB in size.

Comment: I think as a workaround I can merge the files once they are in the blob.  Something strange I am noticing though when trying to set the filename is it creates a folder rather than a file. So:

LOCATION = '/usr-data-engineering/rdp-extracts/cal/test.csv'

Becomes the folder structure on the blob as /usr-data-engineering/rdp-extracts/cal/test.csv/QIDxxxx1.txt, QIDxxxx2.txt etc

Comment: did you try use Copy Data Tool

Comment: Where is this file stored now

Comment: Hi, yes so it looks like i'm going to go ahead with merging the files afterwards.  The copy data tool does work but utilises a concurrency slot for longer.  I'll mark this as resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can produce a single file utilising the copy tool but it works out a bit better using the external table and then merging the files after.